# Any way to map extra mouse buttons to keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: mojave, mouse

My mouse has two other buttons which I think are referred to as button 4 and 5. Is there any way to configure these to trigger a keyboard shortcut like option delete for adobe premiere?

Comment: Usually the manufacturer provides driver and an app that will let you do that. Failing that I believe there are applications that allow you to control USB keyboards, mice, etc. if the manufacturer does not provide mMac software

Comment: There's a much more comprehensive list of software to do this task at  [Logitech Mouse: how can I use additional buttons?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/logitech-mouse-how-can-i-use-additional-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

While not perfect (can't make application specific macros, and doesn't detect every button on my mouse) https://www.usboverdrive.com does exactly what I want and can trigger keyboard shortcuts with the mouse buttons I wanted to use.